# Force HDMI resolution to 1920x1080, best mode available

Tags: hdmi, xorg

I am working on a project that involves a raspberry pi outputting video to tvs. I'd like to have the raspberry pi always output FullHD video.

If it was booted without a display, by default it switched to composite. By adding `force_hdmi_hotplug=1` or something along those lines I got it to always output on HDMI.

However if I power it on without a display, it defaults to a lower resolution (720p?). I could force a specific CEA/DMT mode, but the displays have different refresh rates and progressive/interlaced modes, so I would have to find a mode supported by all.

How would I solve this?

I guess I would have to either:

- configure it to keep the resolution and find the best mode when a tv
  is plugged
- manually poll available modes, try to find the best, and tell to switch to that. How would I change resolution on command line? I have the X server running a single app without a window manager / desktop environment

Comment: AFAIK, Raspberry Pi always uses 720p mode, but upscales it to the 1080p if necessary.

Comment: @lenik, Interesting, I didn't know that. Is there a way to force upscale then? :)

Comment: rPi does full 1080p, not just upscaled.

Answer (score 2):

In the `/boot/config.txt` file you could try to adjust the `framebuffer_width` and `framebuffer_height settings` to `1920x1080`, this will force the image at that resolution through the HDMI port.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that uncommenting the

`disable_overscan=1`

setting in `/boot/config.txt` helps if a black border persists.

Comment: This answer seems to apply to a problem (black border) that the question doesn't mention.

Comment: I agree with you. But...

If a black border persists around your screen, does this not mean that the resolution is not 1920x1080? If the image was cropped, I would agree that the resolution might be 1920x1080, but this is not the case.